# Must close firewall when i access wmi via j-interop

Tags: wmi, firewall, j-interop

If i want to access wmi via j-interop, i must close the firewall, otherwise i will get a "The RPC server is unavailable." error. The remote machine's os is windows server 2008, i don't want to close its firewall, is there any way to solve the question?

Comment: The MSDN documentation explains this topic in detail, try these articles. * [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
* [Connecting Through Windows Firewall (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
* [Connecting to WMI Remotely Starting with Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa822854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)